# How to find the null geodesics?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, geodesics

The metric below was considered in [[Spacetime perspective of Schwarzschild lensing](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0001037v1.pdf)]

$ds^{2}=2f du^{2}-\frac{2}{l^{2}} du dl-\frac{1}{2l^{2}}(d\theta^{2}+\sin^{2}\theta\, d\phi^{2})$

The authors gave null geodesics for this metric as

[image]

where $A,B,C$ are three first integrals of the null geodesics.

I am not sure how the authors got the above equations because from what I understand the null geodesics are given by the equation $g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx_{\mu}}{dt}\frac{dx_{\nu}}{dt}=0$ but I can't see how one can get the above equations from this.

Does anyone know how the authors got the above equations?

Comment: Please *type out* the equations instead of using pictures. It is clear that you already know how to use MathJax, so please do so consistently.

Comment: @Danu, I am just  trying to show exactly how the authors presented the equations.

Comment: I know that; I'm just saying that you should type out all your equations ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation you list 
$$g_{\mu\nu}\partial_\tau x^\mu\partial_\tau x^\nu=0$$
is satisfied by all null-trajectories. However, a *null geodesic* must also satisfy the *geodesic equation* 
$$\partial^2_\tau x^\mu +\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\rho}\partial_\tau x^\nu\partial_\tau x^\rho=0$$
These two equations, taken together, should suffice to determine the null geodesics. The $\Gamma$ symbols are in principle easy to calculate, either by hand or using some computer algebra program.

Since the results in the paper are given by first order differential equations, while the geodesic equation is of second order, one has to integrate once (this explains the presence of the integration constants $A,B,C$).

Comment: how does this goes for Miknowski space. $\ddot{x}^{\mu}$ would lead, in 1+1 dimensions to , say $x=m+m'\sigma $ and $t=l+l'\sigma$, where sigma is the affine parameter. But how does this fit with $g_{\mu,\nu}\dot{x}^{\mu}\dot{x}^{\nu}=0$. Computing the derivatives, I get ${l'}^2-{m'}^2=0$, which  I interpret as a condition.

Comment: @AlexanderCska The condition implies $ l' = \pm m' $ . Which then simply implies $ x = \pm t + a $ i.e. particle moving at the speed of light.

Comment: @M111 thank you for this answer.